# Can't access local file and folder form img src attribute in blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

Tried finding a solution to this with no luck, it may just be my wording through lack of .net vocabulary.  I have created a new folder in my blazor app called "content", under that a folder called "images" (this app will allow images to be uploaded so I want them on the server).

When I go to enter my file src on the img tag, i can't seem to load in the image.  Even the autocomplete window will not show the new content folder, it's like it can't see it.  I added the image in the folder as an existing file too.

[editor auto-fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pqav.png)
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k1cK.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: it might be far easier to refer it from the top most of your website (e.g. `/Content/images/...` or `~/Content/images/...`). IntelliSense often behave weirdly, most of the issue can be resolved by restarting the IDE though.

Comment: @BagusTesa that was my problem, I had to go one step further though and just do a full PC restart

Answer (score 0):

You should put the folder in the wwwroot.
[image]

```
<img src="Content/google.jpg" />
```

[image]

The app run using compiled files (not the files in visual studio explorer). If you try publish the blazor app to folder and open the folder. Only "wwwroot" folder is still there.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using Blazor server, I have a large amount of images that needs to be pulled form the server, hence why i want to pull only what's required.

I found out what I need to do, I have to include a UseStaticFiles() and define a file path in the Program.cs file, then I can use file paths that aren't wwwroot